# Facebook JS API Share Method with Parameters

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, fb.ui, dialog

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: name,
    link: link,
    caption: caption,
    picture: picture,
    description: desc
});
```

This code provides a functionality to pass *caption*, *picture* and other parameters. As far as I know, '**feed**' method is deprecated now and it's better to use '**share**' dialogue. I must generate this data on-the-fly, without any additional pages which includes OG tags.

Is there any way to get the same parameter-based code with '**share**' method?